# Subfigures on multiple pages

Tags: floats, subfloats

I want to have three figures that are each large (taking a full page each) be labeled as

Figure 1.4 A, Figure 1.4 B, Figure 1.4 C, etc.

rather than

Figure 1.4, Figure 1.5, Figure 1.6, etc.

I can make this work with

```
\begin{figure}
\centerline{
\includegraphics[scale=1.1]{figA}
\caption{capA}
\label{fig:A}
}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centerline{
\includegraphics[scale=1.1]{figB}
\caption{capB}
\label{fig:B}
}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centerline{
\includegraphics[scale=1.1]{figC}
\caption{capC}
\label{fig:C}
}
\end{figure}
```

Except for the labels. I've tried stuff with `\begin{subfigure}` and `\pagebreak`, etc., but nothing works correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The `caption` package provides the `\ContinuedFloat` macro for figures that are split over multiple floats. Combined with the `subfigure` environment, as in Matt's answer, to get the subfigure-numbering.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionSubType*[Alph]{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\thefigure\Alph{subfigure}}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}
\caption{First}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{capA}
\label{fig:A}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{capB}
\label{fig:B}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-c}
\subcaption{capC}
\label{fig:C}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Third}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `subcaption` package to get subfigure labeling. Normally you would just include multiple subfigures within a single `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}` environment, but if you want it to break across pages you can't do that. In order to get the numbering to work out, I reset the `subfigure` counter every time I start a new figure.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\subfigurename{Figure \thefigure}

\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{subfigure}{.7\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{sub caption a}
\label{fig:mainfigure:a}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
\setcounter{subfigure}{2}
\begin{subfigure}{.7\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{sub caption b}
\label{fig:mainfigure:b}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
\setcounter{subfigure}{2}
\begin{subfigure}{.7\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{sub caption c}
\label{fig:mainfigure:c}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Here is the figure caption}
\label{fig:mainfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Edited to show how varying positions of `\centering` will effect the final image placement.

[image]

Comment: \centering doesn't actually work for me. Figure isn't centered. I've had success with \centerline{} for some reason but can't make it work with your solution

Comment: @Steve Depending on how wide your subfigures are, and how wide the image is relative to the subfigure, will change where you need `\centering`. I will update. When not sure, you could always just include a `\centerting` inside the `figure` environment, as well as inside the `subfigure` environment. That should cover all cases.